# How to back fill data from a sql join only where count of field is equal to 1 while maintaning records from previous joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-drill, dremio

I have two tables I am able to join like so:

```
select * from 
(select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id )
```

I want to add a third table where I group by email, to back fill data in the join above but I only want to backfill the data for records that have an email count of 1 only. If there are duplicating email addresses for different records they should be excluded.

I Have been trying this query:

```
  select * from 
    (select * from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
    inner join ((select email from table3 group by email
having count(*) =1) t3
     on t3.email = t1.emailaddress)
```

At this point when I coalesce the email field with others in the bigger join I still see records back filled with data while having email counts greater than 1 being backfilled.

i.e

table from LEFT JOIN only:

```
email      missing_id 
a@a.com 
b@b.com
```

table3 data ONLY

```
email       missing_id
a@a.com        1
a@a.com        2
b@b.com        3
```

All tables joined where email only occurs once, should back fill the data in the left join like so:

```
email      missing_id 
a@a.com       
b@b.com        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your first query will return an error in almost any database, because you will have two columns with the same name in the subquery.  But I get the idea.

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want:

```
select . . ., t3.id as missing_id
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     (select t3.email, max(t3.id) as id
      from table3 t3
      group by t3.email
      having count(*) = 1
     ) t3
     on t3.email = t1.emailaddress;
```

This is very close to your query, so I'm not sure if it will fix anything.